# Retrieve parameters from load model in xgboost

Tags: python, xgboost, hyperparameters

I have made a classification model, which has been saved using

```
bst.save_model('final_model.model')
```

in another file i load the model and do testing on my testdata using:

```
bst = xgb.Booster()  # init model
bst.load_model('final_model.model')  # load data
ypred = bst.predict(dtest)  # make prediction
```

Since I use kfold in my training process but need to use the whole test file for testing (so no kfold splitting) it is not possible for me to verify if I still get the exact same results as I should when loading the model in a new file. This made me curious as if there was a way to print my loaded models hyperparameters. After a lot of googling I found a way to do this in R with `xgb.parameters(bst)` or maybe also `xgb.attr(bst)` - but I have found no way to do this in Python. Since I do not use R I have not tested the above lines, but from documentation it seems to do what i need: output the hyperparameters in a loaded model. So can this be done in Python with xgboost?

**EDIT:** I can see that if i instead write `ypred = bst.predict(dtest, ntree_limit=bst.best_iteration)` i get the error `'Booster' object has no attribute 'best_iteration'`. So it seems that the loaded model is not remembering all my hyperparameters. If i write `bst.attributes()` i can get it to output the number of the best iteration and it's eval score - but i don't see how to output the actual hyperparameters used.

Comment: I have found something similar on [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/danielpace/save-xgboost-out-of-fold-predictions). Through a Github post i infered the solution involves a callback. The documentation is really sparse on this, so any help is appreaciated.

Comment: Have the same question, and am really surprised there is no easy way to do this!

Answer (score 1):

**if you had used a xgboost.sklearn.XGBModel model You can then use the function get_xgb_params()**, but there is no equivalent in the base xgboost.Booster class. Remember that a Booster is the BASE model of xgboost, that contains low level routines for training, prediction and evaluation. You can find more information [here](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html)